# How to update HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT after a new subky is added to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx) says:

> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under both the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** and **HKEY_CURRENT_USER** keys. The **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes** key contains default settings that can apply to all users on the local computer. The **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes** key contains settings that apply only to the interactive user. The **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** key provides a view of the registry that merges the information from these two sources. **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** also provides this merged view for applications designed for previous versions of Windows.

Does that mean if I add a subkey to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes` (say a new file extension), the container of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` will update automatically and accordingly?

If not, what should I do?

Comment: On a word, yes. It is handled automatically

Comment: Yes it will. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT is a kind of alias (as is HKEY_CURRENT_USER).

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, Paul Sanders, Thanks, I see.

Comment: HKCR is messy, designed to be the compatibility view for programs that started life in the 16-bit version of Windows.  Always avoid if you can help it.

Comment: HKCR was changed to a merged view in NT 5. This is implemented at runtime by the Windows registry API. Also, the current-user software classes is a separate hive ("%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\UsrClass.dat"), which intentionally does not roam with the user profile. A user's "Software\Classes" key is a symlink to this hive, which is loaded under HKU as "<SID>_Classes". Also, for the handle aliases (not symlinks), HKLM is for "\Registry\Machine", HKU is for "\Registy\User", and HKCU is for "\Registry\User\<SID>". Internally these handle aliases get mapped to real Key handles on first use.

Answer (score 5):

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` is not a real physical [hive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190119044658/https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090204-00/?p=19263) (it stores no data), it is just a merged view of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`. Updates to the underlying keys are instantly visible in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Values in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` override values in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` because when accessing `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, the Registry internals tries to read from `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` first.

Additionally, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is actually an alias/symlink of a key under `HKEY_USERS`.

Comment: If registry *internals*, is reading from `HKCU` **first**, it should mean that results are from the last section read. I.e. from `HKLM`?

Comment: @not2qubit HKCR: Read HKCU first. If the value is there, return it. If the value is not there, read from HKLM.